# JPA 2.1: received org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException using orphanRemoval

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I have 3 enties which have following mapping and I want to use orphanRemoval when I want to delete parent entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EvaluationRequest", schema = "dbo")
public class EvaluationRequestDMO implements java.io.Serializable {

private Set<EvalStatusDMO> evaluationStatuses = new HashSet<EvalStatusDMO>(0);

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "evaluationRequest", orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<EvalStatusDMO> getEvaluationStatuses() {
        return this.evaluationStatuses;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EvaluationStatus")
public class EvalStatusDMO implements Serializable{
    private EvaluationRequestDMO evaluationRequest;
    private EvaluationResponseDMO evaluationResponce;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EvalRequestId", nullable = false)
    public EvaluationRequestDMO getEvaluationRequest() {
        return evaluationRequest;
    }
    public void setEvaluationRequest(EvaluationRequestDMO evaluationRequestDMO) {
        this.evaluationRequest = evaluationRequestDMO;
    }
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EvalResponseId", nullable = false)
    public EvaluationResponseDMO getEvaluationResponce() {
        return evaluationResponce;
    }
    public void setEvaluationResponce(EvaluationResponseDMO evaluationResponceDMO) {
        this.evaluationResponce = evaluationResponceDMO;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EvaluationResponse")
public class EvaluationResponseDMO implements Serializable{
private Set<EvalStatusDMO> evalStatusDMO = new HashSet<EvalStatusDMO>(0);
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "evaluationResponce", orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<EvalStatusDMO> getEvalStatusDMO() {
        return evalStatusDMO;
    }

}
```

Now I want to delete `EvaluationRequest` and `EvaluationResponse` entities:

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteEvaluationInfoByPgSelIdAndProfileId(long programSelectedId, long profileId) {
        List<EvaluationRequestDMO> evaluationRequestDMOList = evaluationRequestDAO.findByProfileIdAndProgramId(profileId, programSelectedId);
        if (evaluationRequestDMOList != null) {
            List<EvaluationResponseDMO> evaluationResponseDMOList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (EvaluationRequestDMO evaluationRequestDMO : evaluationRequestDMOList) {
                if (evaluationRequestDMO.getEvaluationStatuses() != null) {
                    evaluationResponseDMOList.addAll(collect(evaluationRequestDMO.getEvaluationStatuses(), TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer("getEvaluationResponce")));
                }
            }
            filter(evaluationRequestDMOList, PredicateUtils.notNullPredicate());
            evaluationResponseDAO.deleteInBatch(evaluationResponseDMOList);
            evaluationRequestDAO.deleteInBatch(evaluationRequestDMOList);
        }
    }
```

On deleting `evaluationResponseDAO.deleteInBatch(evaluationResponseDMOList);` I get `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException`:
`The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_EvaluationStatus_EvaluationResponse". The conflict occurred in database "unicas_ux", table "dbo.EvaluationStatus", column 'EvalResponseId'`.

I know that I could delete it successfully in the following order:

EvaluationStatusDMO->EvaluationResponceDMO->EvaluationRequestDMO

But, I how can I do it using orphanRemoval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figure out how to solve the issue. My child entity `EvalStatusDMO` has relationg to both `EvaluationResponseDMO` and to `EvaluationRequestDMO`. To remove everithing properly I must clear the set of `EvalStatusDMO` in one of the relations (see below).

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteEvaluationInfoByPgSelIdAndProfileId(long programSelectedId, long profileId) {
    List<EvaluationRequestDMO> evaluationRequestDMOList = evaluationRequestDAO.findByProfileIdAndProgramId(profileId, programSelectedId);
    if (evaluationRequestDMOList != null) {
        List<EvaluationResponseDMO> evaluationResponseDMOList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (EvaluationRequestDMO evaluationRequestDMO : evaluationRequestDMOList) {
            if (evaluationRequestDMO.getEvaluationStatuses() != null) {
                evaluationResponseDMOList.addAll(collect(evaluationRequestDMO.getEvaluationStatuses(), TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer("getEvaluationResponce")));
                evaluationRequestDMO.getEvaluationStatuses().clear();
            }
        }
        filter(evaluationRequestDMOList, PredicateUtils.notNullPredicate());
        evaluationRequestDAO.deleteInBatch(evaluationRequestDMOList);
        evaluationResponseDAO.deleteInBatch(evaluationResponseDMOList);
    }
}
```

So the logic would be follow:

1. for each of `EvaluationRequestDMO` I should clear `EvalStatusDMO`.
2. Remove all 'EvaluationRequestDMO'.
3. Remove all 'EvaluationResponseDMO'.
4. all `EvalStatusDMO` would be removed automatically, because of `orphanRemoval=true`

Answer (score 0):

The order you are deleting is request and then response, right? Let's have a look.

**request**

- has a relationship to status orphanRemoval=true

**response**

- has also a relationship to status, orphanRemoval=true

**status**

- relationship to request --> nullable=false
- relationship to response --> nullable= false

**The problem:**
If you delete the request you configured your entity to delte also its status entities. But at this moment the status has also a relationship to response that still exists and has a reference to it.

This doesn't work. You have to resolve all relationships of status before you can delete it.